# Azure Media Service: Trying to make custom preset encoding job with REST APIs, but the job fails with "Transient Error"

Tags: rest, azure, azure-media-services

I've tried to create custom preset encoding job with REST APIs. So, I've changed the "Configuration" of example request on the documentation(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974289.aspx (Create Job with Version 2.0)) to custom xml preset string

It created a job and seemed to working greatly. But after checking the status of tasks with task API, the job already died with below messages.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/z22KGLl.png]

I also tried XML from prepared requests, but it died with above messages.

However, When I changed the "Configuration" to "H264 Adaptive Bitrate MP4 Set 720p" or other prepared presets, the job worked and created results.

Is there any rules for write custom presets? What does "transient error" mean?

Comment: Hi, Could you tell me what your custom present looks like? Very likely it maybe a format that we don't recognize. You can either paste the XML here or email me at yanmf@microsoft.com. Thanks.